# How to fetch Strapi by slug, and how to populate the categories

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi

I'm trying to fetch post for a react blog with strapi backend using the slug.
I created the custom route and custom controller, but the value returned is missing a few attributes like images and category.
When I fetch using post Id, I use query string to populate the object returned, but I don't know how to had qs to the slug API route.

Below is the custom controller, and the custom route

```
///custom controller

 async findOne(ctx) {
    const { slug } = ctx.params;
    const { query } = ctx;

  
    const entity = await strapi.service('api::article.article').findOne(slug, query);
    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, query);
    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
  }

///Custom Route
  {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/articles/slug/:slug',
        handler: 'custom-controller.findOne',
        config: {
          policies: []
        },
```

This is how I fetch from client in useEffect

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchData = async()=>{
            // const query = qs.stringify({
            //     populate: '*', 
            //     }, {
            //     encodeValuesOnly: true,
            //     });
            const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:1337/api/articles?filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}`)
            console.log(res.data)
            updateState(res.data) 
            
        }
        fetchData()
        setLoading(false)
    },  [slug])
```

I've also tried to use the Entity API Service, but I just couldn't get it to work.
How do I populate the object to include these missing attributes?

Comment: Have you tried using `qs` or `stencil-qs`? library you can use it in React but I most prefer to use `stencil-qs` it is what I am using for more info: https://medium.com/@nettisfabio/better-queries-with-stencil-qs-5c952784d4a6

Answer (score 3):

With Strapi v4 you can do it this way

**1. Create a file in `src/api/article/routes/_custom.js`**

*Please note I put an underscore because:*

> Routes files are loaded in alphabetical order. To load custom routes before core routes, make sure to name custom routes appropriately (e.g. 01-custom-routes.js and 02-core-routes.js).

Source: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/routes.html#creating-custom-routers

```js
module.exports = {
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/articles/:slug',
      handler: 'article.findOne',
      config: {
        auth: false
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

**2. Edit the `src/api/article/controllers/article.js`**

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * article controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::article.article', ({ strapi }) => ({
  // Query by slug
  async findOne(ctx) {
    // thanks to the custom route we have now a slug variable
    // instead of the default id
    const { slug } = ctx.params;
    const entity = await strapi.db.query('api::article.article').findOne({
      where: { slug }
    });
    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);

    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
  },
}));
```

3. Now you can call your api this way:
   `http://localhost:1337/api/articles/my-beautiful-article-about-orange`

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVV0CfgX6Qk
*Note: In the video, custom.js is loaded before post.js ^^*

Answer (score 0):

Very good idea about the underscore but on Strapi version 4.12.5 unfortunately it doesn't work as expected so you need to put a number in front of your custom.js file.

Also, you can go without the custom.js file in the routes folder if in your article.js file instead of this `const { slug } = ctx.params;` you have this `const { id: slug } = ctx.params;`